# comparing paths in java

Tags: java, xpath, path

i've a set of paths like this :

```
body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[2] 
body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/a/h2 
body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/a/span 
body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/a/span[1] 
body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[9]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[8]/a/span 
body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul[4]/li[4]/a/span[1]
```

this is java code which find similar paths and return it :

```
List<String> output= new ArrayList<>();
List<String> hh = new ArrayList<>();
output.add("body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[2]");
output.add("body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/a/h2");
output.add("body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/a/span");
output.add("body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/a/span[1]");
output.add("body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[9]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[8]/a/span");
output.add("body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul[4]/li[4]/a/span[1]");
for(int a=0; a<output.size(); a++)
        {
            for(int b=0; b<output.size(); b++) {
                String chemin = output.get(a);
                if(a != b)
                {
                    String chemin_comparé = output.get(b);
                    while(true) {
                        if(chemin_comparé.indexOf(chemin) != -1 && !output.contains(chemin))
                            hh.add(chemin);
                        if(chemin.contains("/")) {
                            chemin = chemin.substring(0, chemin.lastIndexOf("/"));
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        final ArrayList<String> filteredOutputList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String string1 : hh) {
    boolean stringIsContainedInOtherString = false;
    for (String string2 : hh) {
        if(!string2.equals(string1) && string2.contains(string1)) {
                stringIsContainedInOtherString = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    if(!stringIsContainedInOtherString && !filteredOutputList.contains(string1)) {
        filteredOutputList.add(string1);
    }
}

for(String filteredOutput: filteredOutputList)
    System.out.println(filteredOutput);
```

and it give me a result like this :

```
body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]
body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]
```

which is good but , in my case i want repeat again this function until i'got only one common path by the end result should be like this :

```
body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div/div[2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code inside a function and call it recursively by some criteria. Try something like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        output.add("body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[2]");
        output.add("body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/a/h2");
        output.add("body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/a/span");
        output.add("body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/a/span[1]");
        output.add("body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[9]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[8]/a/span");
        output.add("body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul[4]/li[4]/a/span[1]");
        List<String> hh = findCommonSubstring(output);
        for(String filteredOutput: hh)
            System.out.println(filteredOutput);

    }

    private static List<String> findCommonSubstring(List<String> output) {
        List<String> hh = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int a=0; a<output.size(); a++)
        {
            for(int b=0; b<output.size(); b++) {
                String chemin = output.get(a);
                if(a != b)
                {
                    String chemin_compare = output.get(b);
                    while(true) {
                        if(chemin_compare.indexOf(chemin) != -1 && !output.contains(chemin))
                            hh.add(chemin);
                        if(chemin.contains("/")) {
                            chemin = chemin.substring(0, chemin.lastIndexOf("/"));
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        final ArrayList<String> filteredOutputList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String string1 : hh) {
            boolean stringIsContainedInOtherString = false;
            for (String string2 : hh) {
                if(!string2.equals(string1) && string2.contains(string1)) {
                        stringIsContainedInOtherString = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
            if(!stringIsContainedInOtherString && !filteredOutputList.contains(string1)) {
                filteredOutputList.add(string1);
            }
        }

        if (filteredOutputList.size()>1)
            return findCommonSubstring(filteredOutputList);
        return filteredOutputList;
    }
```

Comment: it works now , i had  problem with recursif functions :D , now it's clear ! , thanks you